# Find the user under which a Ubuntu service runs?

Tags: permissions, services, chown, cassandra

I have a Cassandra service on my Ubuntu but I cannot figure under what user this service runs. I know how to find the owner and the permissions of files and directories. But how can I do this for a Ubuntu service. Assuming the service is just an executable file, how can I find the location of a particular service?

Comment: If the application is running - "ps" might help you, for example. Search for your process on the list and check what user owns the process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ps -ef` to known who is running cassandra.

All services are located in `/etc/init.d/`.

If you are not running cassandra as a service, you can search where is the program with the `whereis` command:

```
$ whereis cassandra
```

Comment: But it is not running, I cannot start it due to permissions problems.

Comment: Open the file `/etc/init.d/cassandra` and search if you can see a line like `daemon --user $CASS_USER` (like in this file https://gist.github.com/sgomezvillamor/5458309)

Comment: I see this: install -d -ocassandra -gcassandra -m755 `dirname $PIDFILE`. And also: start-stop-daemon -S -c cassandra -a /usr/sbin/cassandra -q -p "$PIDFILE" -t >/dev/null || return 1. It looks like it is running as a cassandra user?

Comment: You are right !